# Is there a way to find the attributes of an sobject in apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Is there a way to find the attributes of an SObject in Apex? 
For example Account object has urlNew attribute. I would like to get the Url using Account.SObjectType.getDescribe() or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got something like an Account then you can use the [StandardController](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=standardController|StandardController) to get a [PageReference](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_system_pagereference.htm).

E.g.

```
PageReference acctViewPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(account).view();
string viewUrl = acctViewPage.getUrl();
```

Incidentally, the [Salesforce StackExchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) site is a great place for asking Salesforce specific questions.